# Como funciona relação entre a mesma tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

- A performance muda? (Em comparação com tabelas diferentes)
- Em qual caso isso poderia ser usado?
- É recomendável?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É perfeitamente possível uma tabela possuir relacionamentos com ela mesma. Existem vários modelos de dados que necessitam de tal abordagem:

- Árvore: cada nó faz referência ao nó pai, sendo que o nó raiz não faz referência a nada, ficando com o campo nulo

  [image: Exemplo de árvore]
- Lista: cada nó faz referência ao próximo nó, sendo que o último nó não faz referência a nada, ficando com o campo nulo. Para evitar que sejam criadas árvores usando este campo, é possível criar um índice que não permita valores duplicados, entretanto isso depende do SGDB, pois só vai funcionar se o mesmo ignorar os valores nulos do índice.

  [image: Exemplo de lista]
- Ciclo: cada nó faz referência ao próximo nó, como na lista, sendo que o último sempre faz referência ao primeiro nó, fechando assim o ciclo
- Mista: é possível ainda, combinar várias dessas possibilidades em uma única estrutura, como na árvore abaixo, em que os filhos encontram-se em fila:

  [image: Mista entre árvore e lista: árvore com filhos em lista]

  Ou ainda uma lista duplamente ligada, em que cada elemento aponta para o próximo, e também para o anterior.

Recomendável? Acho que sim, sempre que quiser montar uma dessas estruturas de dados, e armazenar elas de forma relacional.

Agora, falando sobre performance... bem isso depende mais das queries dos que da estrutura de dados. Por exemplo, na estrutura de árvore, é muito rápido achar o pai de um nó, pois existe uma referência direta (Foreign Key, ou FK) que faz uma busca sobre uma chave-primária (Primary Key, ou PK) o que é muito rápido. Entretanto, não será tão rápido achar os filhos de um nó, pois terá de achar entre todos os registros, quais deles possuem referência para a PK do pai cujos filhos deseja achar... dito isso, para ter performance é recomendável a criação de um índice sobre a coluna da FK, de forma a tornar o processo mais ágil.

Comment: Cuide somente para não gerar referencia circular, caso esteja utilizando algum ORM como o Hibernate ou NHibernate ou Entity Framework, já tive problemas com esse tipo de estrutura causando referencia circular. É só uma observação.

Comment: @Fernando: neste caso terá de ser consultada a documentação do ORM. Alguns requerem uma estrutura específica no banco de dados, podendo suportar ou não uma ou outra situação específica.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Mas o banco permite criar o FK do pai como NULL?

Comment: @Laerte Permite sim. A não ser que o campo não seja anulável... isso é uma configuração do campo.

Answer (score 2):

Quanto ao desempenho, não sei em detalhes, mas certamente não é uma operação pesada.

Quanto à situação onde ela pode ser usada, vai ai em exemplo:

Uma tabela chamada contato, que pode ser do tipo pergunta ou resposta.

```
CREATE TABLE contato (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 tipoDeContato CHAR(1) NOT NULL, <-- imaginemos aqui que pode ser P OU R
 mensagem VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 idContatoResposta INTEGER REFERENCES contato(id) 
);
```

Com isso, pode-se criar um registro na tabela contato, e responde-lo com outro contato.
OBS: Os campos que importam para entender a lógica são id e idContatoResposta. 
Os outros dois podem ser ignorados, estão ai para enriquecer o sentido do exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Não há impacto de performance quando uma tabela referencia a si mesma. Isso é muito comum em estruturas hierárquicas, por exemplo, quando um nó referencia um nó pai que está contido na mesma tabela.

Mesmo nos projetos que trabalho envolvendo Symfony2 e Doctrine2, existe um [recurso nativo](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) para implementar chaves estrangeiras na mesma tabela.

Pesquise por **self-referencing foreign keys** que você descobrirá mais a respeito :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo esse tipo relação para formar hierarquias e menus com submenus. E nunca tive problemas com performance quanto a isso.

Segue exemplo da tabela de menu:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordem` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```