# Modelar Banco de Dados - Auto relacionamento

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

## Meu Caso

Tenho uma tabela `empresa`, essa tabela possui campos conhecidos como `cnpj`, `razão social` e `login`. Essa mesma empresa poderá cadastrar outra em seu catálogo de empresas. A empresa cadastrada por ela será apenas visível para ela, e não para outras.

## O que pensei

Estou lidando com um caso de auto relacionamento, correto. Colocaria um campo na tabela `empresa` apontando para o `cnpj` da empresa cadastrante. Ai quando eu precisar exibir, é só filtrar pelas empresas cadastradas pela empresa x. Tem como eu colocar o cnpj e cnpj_estrangeiro como chave primária composta ?

Comment: Perfeitamente possível. Veja essa resposta.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8433/36350

Comment: Como sou meio fraco em SQL, eu criaria outra tabela e relacionaria a EMPRESA 1 com a EMPRESA 2. não criaria nada na tabela EMPRESA.

Comment: Se você colocar cnpj e cnpj_estrangeiro como chave primária, como irá cadastrar a primeira empresa no banco?

Comment: Respota explicada no link abaixo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8408/como-funciona-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-a-mesma-tabela/8433#8433