# Relacionar Tabela MYSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma Igreja. Tenho uma tabela de cadastro de pessoas, porém preciso de relacionar esta tabela com ela mesmo. Quero relacionar nesta mesma tabela todo mundo que tiver algum parentesco e exibir uma tela de famílias.

Seguinte: Cadastro nela 6 pessoas sendo elas:  `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` , `E` e `F`.  De repente, descubro que a pessoa `B` é pai da pessoa `E`. A pessoa `A` é cunhada do `B` e primo do `C`. Como relaciono isto?

A ideia é quando eu selecionar uma pessoa, poder listar todas as pessoas ligadas a ela. Pai, mãe, primos, ... a diferença é que todos estão na mesma tabela.

Comment: O que procura isso aqui é, padawan: [Como funciona relação entre a mesma tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8433/42307) . Duplicada sua pergunta está.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como funciona relação entre a mesma tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8408/como-funciona-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-entre-a-mesma-tabela)

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa sugestão seria você criar uma outra tabela, onde você poderia armazenar o relacionamento entre estas pessoas,

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Parentesco(
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_pessoa1 INT(6),
  id_pessoa2 INT(6),
  parentesco VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Fazendo Joins(Junções) para obter os relacionamento desejados. 
Com isso você ganha um maior controle, escalabilidade e integridade.
Fazendo com que você possa ter o relacionamento de N para N.

Comment: Melhor forma mesmo, eu só criaria mais uma tabela dos tipos de parentescos, e com isso, nessa tabela Parentesco ao invés de ter parentesco teria tipo_parentesco_id, ficaria mais normalizado o banco